# Any non-private API alternative for this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, iphone-privateapi

My app was recently rejected due to using a private API (`addTextField:` method for `UIAlertView`, which is quite useful, might I add).

Is there any non-private alternative to `UIAlertView`'s undocumented `addTextFieldWithValue:label:`?

Thanks SO much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create the text field as a subview of the UIAlertView

```
// Ask for Username and password.
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:_title message:@"\n \n \n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
// Adds a username Field
utextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
utextfield.placeholder = @"Username";
[utextfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
utextfield.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
[utextfield setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[utextfield setDelegate:self];
[alertView addSubview:utextfield];

// Show alert on screen.
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Comment: Nice trick. (Small note: missed a release on the utextfield.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Open Source code on GitHub for adding UITextFields to a UIAlertView.

http://github.com/enormego/EGOTextFieldAlertView