# Build failed : symbol(s) not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, linker

iTunes reject my app so I have to modify it. I'm doing it and now I cannot launch the app on the emulator :

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emars-hgjxnbewvbrekiepjbfkvodcrvtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/emars.app/emars normal i386
    cd "/Users/user/TRAVAIL/MMW/iphone application V1.0/e-mars"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emars-hgjxnbewvbrekiepjbfkvodcrvtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emars-hgjxnbewvbrekiepjbfkvodcrvtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emars-hgjxnbewvbrekiepjbfkvodcrvtk/Build/Intermediates/emars.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/emars.build/Objects-normal/i386/emars.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Objc -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -lz.1.1.3 -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/emars-hgjxnbewvbrekiepjbfkvodcrvtk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/emars.app/emars
```

And here is the end :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._title", referenced from:
      -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] in FirstViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe it requires one library that I don't included (I stopped dealing about libraries since a lot)...

**EDIT: The error is coming from the new code I've alter because if the reject of the app on the store**

This WAS my code (running but rejected by ItunesConnect)

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login et mot de passe" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler"  otherButtonTitles:@"Sauvegarder", nil];
        [alertView addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Login"];
        [alertView addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Mot de passe"];
        // Username
        textfieldName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        textfieldName.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
        textfieldName.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        textfieldName.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        // Password
        textfieldPassword = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        textfieldPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textfieldPassword.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
        textfieldPassword.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
        textfieldPassword.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textfieldPassword.secureTextEntry = YES;
        [alertView show];
```

And this is the code that getting this error :

```
// Ask for Username and password.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:_title message:@"\n \n \n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

        // Adds a username Field
        textfieldName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)]; 
        textfieldName.placeholder = @"Login";
        [textfieldName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        textfieldName.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
        [textfieldName setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textfieldName setDelegate:self];
        [alertView addSubview:textfieldName];


        Show alert on screen.
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
```

Thanks for help me !

Comment: why did Apple reject your app? And why are you trying to access the `._title` property of `UIViewController`? That's probably a private / non-supported thing.  Better to put (and access) your `title` property into your subclassed view controller.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks for your quick ask. Because "We found the following non-public API/s in your app: addTextFieldWithValue:label:" Son i'm trying that code :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784134/any-non-private-api-alternative-for-this

Comment: @Michael : if I comment the code I've edited, the app build so I edit my first post ;-)

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you now, Clement!

Comment: @Michael :it's not working but I "found" the place of the error :-) it's better than before haha

Answer (score 5):

`_title` is not a valid ivar to use. It is defined in `UIViewController` which is why you don't get the undefined error, but it's declared as `@package` which means it's internal. In short, don't use `_title`.

Comment: Same if you try to use `_view`